# Prevent infinite scrolling of carousel and make it static

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to disable auto scrolling. I have added "false" to bs-interval but still it scrolls automatically/

My code is here

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <input class="workflowTitle" value="Accordion Item #1" />
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">

                    <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false">

                        <div class="">

                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>

                        </div>



                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">

                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="">Next</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `data-bs-ride="carousel"` to `data-bs-ride="false"`.

See the snippet below.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
  <div class="accordion-item">
    <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
      <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <input class="workflowTitle" value="Accordion Item #1" />
      </button>
    </h2>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
      <div class="accordion-body">

        <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="false" data-bs-interval="false">

          <div class="">

            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>

          </div>

          <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="false">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>First slide label</h5>
                  <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                  <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="carousel-item">
                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                </p>
                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                  <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                  <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="">Previous</span>
          </button>
            <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">

            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="">Next</span>
          </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: You need to also remove `data-carousel-ride` from `#carouselExampleControls`. If you don't, it still slides automatically.