# Styling the bootstrap carousel like a wizard

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to design a bootstrap wizard using a carousel like
I want to disable auto scrolling. I have added "false" to bs-interval but still it scrolls automatically

My code is here

```html
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <input class="workflowTitle" value="Accordion Item #1" />
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">

                    <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel" data-bs-interval="false">

                        <div class="">

                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>

                        </div>



                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">

                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="">Next</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the same question: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74111660/prevent-infinite-scrolling-of-carousel-and-make-it-static

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just done some testing on my local machine, and I was able to reproduce the same bug, however after some Google searches I stumbled onto this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/36526#issuecomment-1149829242) that has the exact same problem as you. `data-bs-ride="carousel"` conflicts with the `data-bs-interval` making it scroll continuously. If you remove `data-bs-ride="carousel"` from the `<div id="carouselExampleDark">`, it will stop the auto scrolling issue. I hope this solves your issue, if not please let me know, I might be able to help you out further.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    <input class="workflowTitle" value="Accordion Item #1" />
                </button>
            </h2>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">

                    <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide"  data-bs-interval="false">

                        <div class="">

                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
                            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>

                        </div>



                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="carousel-item active">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="carousel-item">
                                <p class="d-block w-100">I have a Bootstrap Accordion I need to prevent opening of the accordion when textbox is clicked While, if anyone clicks outside the texbox (blue color region) let it expand and shrink as usual.

                                </p>
                                <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
                            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="">Previous</span>
                        </button>
                        <button class="" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">

                            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="">Next</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```